# scalamock create basic setup and easily change it

Tags: scala, scalamock

I started writing my own MockSetter, to make some basic mocks before each tests, on in every of it be able to change of of them or add new one.
Trait for Spec looks like:

```
trait MocksSetter extends MockFactory with BeforeAndAfterEach { self: Suite =>

    type PositionWithMockTuple = (Int, (() => CallHandler[Any]))
    private var standardMocks: Seq[PositionWithMockTuple] = Seq.empty

    def setupStandardMocks(mocks: Seq[PositionWithMockTuple]) = {
        standardMocks = mocks
    }

    //Replaces current standard mock in a given position
    def replaceMock(position: Int, newMockedFunc: () => CallHandler[Any]) = {
        val updatedMocks = standardMocks.map {
            case (pos, _) if pos == position => (pos, newMockedFunc)
            case (pos, mf) => (pos, mf)
        }
        standardMocks = updatedMocks
    }

    //Puts new mock in the end
    def insertMock(newMockedFunc: () => CallHandler[Any]) = {
        standardMocks = standardMocks :+ ((standardMocks.last._1 + 1, newMockedFunc))
    }

    override def beforeEach(): Unit = {
        standardMocks.foreach {
            case (_, mockFunc) => mockFunc().once()
        }
        super.beforeEach()
    }
}
```

but when I try to pass mocks:

```
[error]  found   : org.scalamock.handlers.CallHandler[Boolean]
[error]  required: org.scalamock.handlers.CallHandler[Any]
[error] Note: Boolean <: Any, but class CallHandler is invariant in type R.
[error] You may wish to define R as +R instead. (SLS 4.5)
[error]   setupStandardMocks(Seq((1, () => someMethodMock(false))))
```

Is it possible to achieve this goal ?
My idea is simple, before all tests save basic mocks, which are executed before each test ( by using `.once()` ). Of course different specs may differ between each other, and when doing tests there is a lot of code repeated in every test. If there are for example 10 methods inside, for each test I need to write mocks for every method, and change only what is needed.

Would be nice to make it using basic setup and change according to specific test.

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution can be done in easier way.
In spec we can create abstract class with parameters.
We will run spec by doing

```
"x y z" in new StandardMocks(onlyOneParamChanged = "xyz") {
...
}
```

Of course class parameters will have default values, which we can override easily.
Inside class do the mocking stuff by takich parameters and thats it.